# Revolution Slider on Wordpress creates space under menus?

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

As you can see, when I use the rev slider, I get some padding / margin under the menus:

http://deekwa.com/nibh-stage/hero7-nibh

But when I just use a fixed header within the page I get no such padding:

http://deekwa.com/nibh-stage/

And I cannot find any CSS for this?

Paul

Answer (score 0):

in your web page there is css for

```
    #primary {
         margin-top: 20px;
    }
```

just add this css instead of this

```
    #primary {
        margin-top: -20px;
    }
```

That's it gap between menu and slider is not anymore.

Comment: Many thanks. That work's. I add this to the CSS just for the slider. Great.